# Question on monoid algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $G$ be a finite monoid.

> Question 1: In case the monoid algebra $A=kG$ is weakly symmetric (meaning soc(P)=top(P) for each indecomposable projective modules), is $kG$ even symmetric (meaning $A \cong D(A)$)?
>
> Question 2: In case $G=M_n(F_q)$ the monoid of matrices over a finite field $F_q$ with $q$ elements under matrix multiplication, are the dimensions of the simple $kG$-modules known? (for certain fields $k$ such as $\mathbb{C}$, finite fields or even in general)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to Question 2 is that if the characteristic of $k$ is not that of $F_q$ then $kM_n(F_q)$ is isomorphic to the direct

product of $k$ with the algebras $M_{n_j}(kGL(j,q))$ where $n_j$ is the number of $j$-dimensional subspaces of $F_q^n$ as $j$ ranges from $1$ to $n$ and so we know the dimensions of the simples as long as we know them for the general linear groups, so we know them over $\mathbb C$ for example. This was proved for $k=\mathbb C$ by Okninski and Putcha and in general by Kovacs. A proof appears in my book.

If the characteristic of $k$ is the same as that of  $F_q$ it is known that every irreducible representation of $M_n(F_q)$ restricts to an irreducible representation of $GL(n,q)$ by a result of Kuhn.  Also every irreducible representation of $GL(n,q)$ extends to $M_n(F_q)$ but not uniquely.  So the dimensions are the same as for the general linear group but we don’t know a description of all simples in this case.

The answer to your first question I don’t immediately know.  What if you take a quiver and divide out the paths of some length greater than or equal to $2$.  Do we get weakly symmetric without symmetric?  This is a semigroup algebra.    I think if the the monoid is von Neumann regular, these are equivalent.

Comment: $A=KQ/J^n$ where $J$ is the radical is weakly-symmetric only if it is symmetric (since $Q$ has to be a oriented cycle so A is a Nakayama algebra), so that does not work. For regular monoids it is even true that symmetric is equivalent to being Frobenius, it is theorem 15.6 in your book.

Comment: That’s what I remembered but I didn’t have the book in front of me.  In general any monomial quiver algebra is a semigroup algebra.  Do you have any examples there?

Comment: No, monomial and Frobenius implies that it is a Nakayama algebra, where symmetric is the same as weakly symmetric. It is also true for representation-finite algebras over an algebraically closed field that symmetric is the same as weakly symmetric.

Comment: In the non-semisimple case, is $kM_n(F_q)$ then symmetric?

Comment: I think it isn't.

Comment: I checked that $F_2M_2(F_2)$ is not symmetric.  I don't  know if it is weakly symmetric.

Comment: Actually in characteristic p $kM_n(F_p)$ is not self injective.  Does this mean it is not weakly symmetric?

Comment: Yes, weakly-symmetric implies selfinjective. Is the quiver of this algebra known at least in small examples? I wonder whether it even might have finite global or Gorenstein dimension.

Comment: It has infinite global dimension.  I don't know the quiver although for 2x2 over F2 it should be doable.